# C++ как записать свой код в поток другого процесса без использования dll

Tags: c++, функции, code-injection

Не знаю как можно осуществить такую вещь: `записать свой код либо функцию в поток другого процесса без использования dll`. И есть ли вообще возможность сделать такое? Если есть возможном с кусочком (желательно простого) кода.

Comment: Откройте microsoft MSDN  раздел processes, почитайте ф-ции ReadProcessMemory WriteProcessMemory  CreateRemoteThread VirtualQueryEx.

Comment: В дополнение к вышесказанному - SetThreadContext еще может пригодиться.

Comment: "код в поток процесса" - некорректное выражение. Код пишется в память, а у всех потоков (threads) память процесса одинаковая. Регистры потока могут ссылаться на память - да. Их можно менять.

Comment: Вопрос слишком обширный, по этому вопросу можно целую статью писать. Первое - то же что и с использованием dll, перехват процесса, а второе - генерация "инжекционного" кода. Для этого нужно знать ассемблер, и особенности генерации кода разными версиями с. В отдельных случаях понимать где и зачем Rellocation Table. Отдельный пункт - привелегии и адресное пространство OS. Приведите пример что вы делаете, возможно вас поправят. Внимательно полистайте страницы журнала хакер, или готовые примеры инжекции.